# Area of a cyclic quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry, circles, area

**Question:**

The distance $SR$ from $PQ$ is 7cm and **arc** $SR$ is 48cm and arc $SP \cong$ arc $QR$. Then *find*  the area of quadrilateral $SRQP$($PQRS$ are taken in order and $O$ is centre).
[image: Question figure]

**What we(me and my friends) tried:**

---

**Approach 1:**
[image: My work]

In construction,$OM\perp PQ$.
Let radius of circle be $r$.
By Pythagoras theorem:
$$SM=MR=\sqrt{r^2-49}$$
$$SR=2\sqrt{r^2-49}$$
$$\text{Area} \triangle SOR =7\sqrt{r^2-49}$$
$$ \text{Area} \triangle SOP=\triangle  ROQ=\dfrac{7r}{2}$$
Area of quadrilateral:
$$7r+7\sqrt{r^2-49}$$
Now $\angle OMR=\angle OMS=\theta$
$$\angle SOR=2\theta$$

By using radian arc formula:
$$48=r\cdot 2\theta\dfrac{ \pi}{180}$$
$$\theta=\dfrac{4320}{\pi r}$$
In $\triangle OMR$:
$$\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{7}{r}$$
$$\cos\bigg(\dfrac{4320}{\pi r}\bigg)=\dfrac 7r$$
I have no idea how to simplify this.

---

**Approach 2:**
[image: A-2]
Let $MN$ be $x$,$\angle SOR=\theta,\angle ROQ=\angle SOP=\phi$ and $\phi=\dfrac{180-\theta}{2}$
Radius of circle:
$$ON=OM+MN=7+x$$
$$\text{Area}\triangle SOR=\dfrac 12 (7+x)^2 \sin \theta$$
$$\text{Area}\triangle SOP=\text{Area}\triangle ROQ=\dfrac 12 (7+x)^2 \sin \phi$$
$$\text{Area of quadrilateral }PQRS=\dfrac 12 (7+x)^2 \sin \theta+ (7+x)^2 \sin \phi$$
$$=\dfrac 12 (7+x)^2 \sin \theta+ (7+x)^2 \sin \bigg(\dfrac{180-\theta}{2}\bigg)$$

And
$$\frac \theta {360}[2\pi(7+x)]= 48$$
Two equations and two variables, so it might be solved( but I was not able to do so ).

---

How to solve this question?

Thanks!

---

As per comments, it should be solved by numerical approximation.

Comment: You wrote $SR = 2\sqrt{r^2-49}$. You can equate that to $48$ and calculate $r$. With the radius known, finding the area of the quadrilateral will be easy.

Comment: The numbers are too perfect for that to be arc $SR$. However I will investigate that possibility, since it was written in your question.

Comment: Please check the original question. I strongly suspect that it should just be $SR = 48$, which has also been mentioned by player3236.

Comment: @Toby Mak [Original question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayVmK.jpg)

Comment: If so, this question cannot be solved without some kind of numerical approximation. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos+x+%3D+7x%2F24) gives $\theta \approx 1.21008$ radians. Out of curiosity, where is this question from?

Comment: @YouKnowMe, what's the answer/option? Does it correspond to chord = 48 or not?

Comment: Whenever you have segment and arc involved, it is messy. If you know the angle and find arc or segment, it is fine but if arc and segments are known and you have to find subtended angle, it is not possible by hand without some guesses / approximation. Btw your equation in the first approach should just be $cos (\frac{24}{r}) = \frac{7}{r}$. Radius comes to $\approx 20 \,$ cm and angle subtended at the center by the arc is $\approx 140^0$.

Comment: @Math Lover How did $\cos\bigg(\dfrac{4320}{\pi r}\bigg)=\dfrac 7r$ become $\cos (\frac{24}{r}) = \frac{7}{r}$?

Comment: Keeping the angle in radian. Arc of length $r$ will subtend an angle of $1$ radian ($2\pi r$ length subtends an angle of $2\pi$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.-Putting angle $\angle{SOR}=2\theta$ you have the system
$$r\theta=24\\r\cos(\theta)=7$$ so you have the trascendental equation $7\theta=24\cos(\theta)$.  An approximate solution is $\theta\approx 1.21$ so $r\approx\dfrac{24}{1.21}\approx19.83471$.

Now $SR=2r\sin(\theta)$ and the required area $A$ is given by
$$A=\frac{7(PQ+SR)}{2}=\frac{7(2r+2r\sin(\theta))}{2}$$

Comment: $1.21 radians=69.32789 degrees$

Comment: Thanks for answering :-) I was going to self answer it to close it.

Comment: @Wolgwang: You are welcome. The "difficulty" in your problem is the trascendental equation you need to solve, nothing more.